# Having trouble pulling images in php

Tags: php

I'm missing something to pull the images correctly but I'm having trouble figuring what what's missing.

```
            echo "
        <div class=\"large-4\">
                <img src=\"images\"{$row['movies_fimg']}\" alt=\"{$row['movies_title']}\">
                <h2>{$row['movies_title']}</h2>
                <p>{$row['movies_year']}</p>
                <a href=\"details.php?movie={$row['movies_id']}\">more...</a>
        </div>
        ";
```

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like? Does the image file exist? Does it exist in an `images/` directory? Should that be `/images/` instead?

Comment: @Len_D there are no slashes here. He's escaping characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need a double quote inside `src` attr of img

```
<img src=\"images\"{$row['movies_fimg']}\"
                 ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you:

(Added a `/` in the src attr. so if you don't need it delete it)

```
    echo "
        <div class='large-4'>
            <img src='images/" . $row['movies_fimg'] . "' alt='" . $row['movies_title'] . "'>
            <h2>" . $row['movies_title'] . "</h2>
            <p>" . $row['movies_year'] . "</p>
            <a href='details.php?movie=" . $row['movies_id'] . "'>more...</a>
        </div>
    ";
```

Answer (score 0):

An exta quote here: `<img src=\"images\"{$row['movies_fimg']}\"` where a forward slash should be.

Should be:

```
echo "
    <div class=\"large-4\">
            <img src=\"images/{$row['movies_fimg']}\" alt=\"{$row['movies_title']}\">
            <h2>{$row['movies_title']}</h2>
            <p>{$row['movies_year']}</p>
            <a href=\"details.php?movie={$row['movies_id']}\">more...</a>
    </div>
    ";
```